# Typescript: Object of arrow functions that return an Object

Tags: typescript, express-session

Given the following,

```js
...
const NODE_ENV = 'development';
const sessionConfig = {
 'development': ():session.SessionOptions => ({
   'store': storeConfig.development(),
   'secret': 'REDACTED',
   'resave': false,
   'saveUninitialized': true,
   'cookie': {'secure': false},
   'genid': () => uuidv4()
  }),
  'testing': ():session.SessionOptions => ({
    'store': storeConfig.testing(),
    'secret': 'REDACTED',
    'resave': false,
    'saveUninitialized': true,
    'cookie': {'secure': false},
    'genid': () => uuidv4()
  }),
  'production': ():session.SessionOptions => ({
    'store': storeConfig.production(),
    'secret': process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'REDACTED',
    'resave': false,
    'saveUninitialized': true,
    'cookie': {
      'secure': process.env.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE === 'true' || false
    },
    'genid': () => uuidv4()
  })
}
{NODE_ENV} = process.env,
sessionEnvConfig = sessionConfig[NODE_ENV],
sessionEnvObject:session.SessionOptions = sessionEnvConfig(),
sessionObject = session(sessionEnvObject);

export default sessionObject;
```

Whenever I attempt to compile with tsc, I get this error:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ development: () => SessionOptions; testing: () => SessionOptions; production: () => SessionOptions; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ development: () => SessionOptions; testing: () => SessionOptions; production: () => SessionOptions; }'.
```

I cannot seem to wrap my head around this TS error? Can anyone here explain what this error **means**, or at least what I'm doing wrong? I'm like 90% certain it's an error regarding how I've (not) defined the object's type, but I do not know how to approach that.
I also have this environment.d.ts file:

```js
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      [key: string]: string | undefined;
      NODE_ENV?: 'development' | 'production' | 'testing' ;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because Typescript is inferring `string` for `NODE_ENV`, instead of one of your constant values.

Because of that, Typescript isn't sure that the `NODE_ENV` (being a `string`) corresponds to any key in your object.

You can try this:

```
const NODE_ENV = 'development' as const;
```

That way you narrow down the possible values for `NODE_ENV` to just `development`.

Also, try declaring your `process.env` like this:

```
declare const process: {
    env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production' | 'development' | 'testing';
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the process.env declaration did not work, I'm accepting this answer as it did explain the issue and led me to a resolution. Thank you.